# Minify CSS and JS files with JCH optimizer for Joomla

Tags: javascript, css, performance, joomla, minify

I have installed JCH optimize plugin in Joomla-3 OS property base website to Minify CSS and javascript.

I have activated only Minify CSS and Minify Javascript options, please see the attached file (ss I need these two options to improve in Google PageSpeed Insights)

But I don't see any improvement in Google PageSpeed Insights after Minifying CSS and JS.

If I activate 'Combine CSS Files' and 'Combine JavaScript Files',
it's working fine, but the template has broken format and highlighted text.

Comment: Please contact the developer of JCH Optimize. If nothing is happening or it's causing problems with your site, then it's a bug that we cannot do anything about here at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

As the developer of JCH Optimize, from my experience, most of the problems people experience with the plugin is either from incorrectly configuring the plugin or errors on the website.

Every website is different so needs to configured individually so I strongly recommend reading the documentation and tutorials on how to configure and use the plugin before trying to install it on your live site, something a lot of people fail to do.

If you have errors in your javascript file or parsing errors in your css file, while they may seem to work well as individual files you WILL have trouble when these files are combined so it is best to check for these and correct them first. Check for javascript errors in your browser's javascript console and you can check for parsing errors in css using http://csslint.net/. Ignore errors about vendor specific rules like 'Unknown @ rule: @-ms-keyframes'.

However there is ample support and information on the website for users of the plugin at https://www.jch-optimize.net/. Subscribers can get premium support and assistance in configuring the plugin on your site so no need to post support requests on stackoverflow.

BTW the answer by itoctopus is incorrect. The plugin generates cache based on the name of the files or a hash of the content in inline styles/script, so any content generated on the fly will generate another cache. There's also a tutorial on the site that describes how to handle these kinds of situation to prevent excess cache from being generated. It would have served him well to read through the documentation before using.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried JCH Optimize for a couple of major clients and it was a disaster. This is because JCH Optimize often caches CSS styles that shouldn't be cached (some CSS styles are generated on the fly), the same goes for JS code.

You have 3 options:

- Disable JCH Optimize on certain extensions (there's a way to do it from JCH Optimize)
- Completely disable caching on JCH Optimize
- Merge those static CSS and JS files yourself

Comment: JCH optimizer is not working for minifying CSS, JS and HTML without activation of combine CSS , Javascript and GZip. If I activate Combine CSS, Combine Javascript and Gzip it ruins the template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed JCH optimize for OS Property component and plugins, so I can not disable for this one.  I am looking for another .htacces code or plugin for this problem.

Comment: Read the documentation. You can exclude a file if it is dynamically generated.